# How can i add a base constructor to the database connection class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, database-connection

I use EfFeatureDal class as a database connection class and i use constructor for this connection. But when i need to call this class from FeatureList i cant add these connection constructor's parameters thats why i need base constructor on EfFeatureDal but i cant add it?

```
public class FeatureList:ViewComponent
{

    FeatureManager featureManager = new FeatureManager(new EfFeatureDal());

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke() 
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class EfFeatureDal : GenericRepository<Feature>, IFeatureDal
{
    public EfFeatureDal(Context1 _db) : base(_db)
    {
    }

    public EfFeatureDal() { }

}
```

I got this error on base constructor:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required parameter '_db' of
> 'GenericRepository.GenericRepository(Context1)'

```
public class FeatureList:ViewComponent
{

    FeatureManager featureManager = new FeatureManager(new EfFeatureDal());

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke() 
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I got this error when i delete base constructor on new FeatureManager(new EfFeatureDal()):

> Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required parameter '_db' of 'EfFeatureDal.EfFeatureDal(Context1)'

Comment: We can't read those images. **Please don't post images of technical information**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i need to call this class from FeatureList i cant add these
> connection constructor's parameters thats why i need base constructor
> on EfFeatureDal but i cant add it?

Well, It would be perfect it if you would have been shared FeatureManager details. However, If your EfFeatureDal class has implicitly defined a constructor within it as following:

```
 public EfFeatureDal(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }
```

As it has [constructor dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection), you must have to pass the constructor if you would like to create its instance somewhere. But this is not the common practice we do everyday.

What you can do is, if you need to access EfFeatureDal methods or anything you have defined there, you can call it in derived class by injecting its interface within derived class constructor. Have a look in following example:

```
public class FeatureList : ViewComponent
    {

        private readonly IEfFeatureDal _efFeatureDal;

        public FeatureList(IEfFeatureDal featureDal)
        {

            _efFeatureDal = featureDal;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
           _efFeatureDal... // Anything you want to call from your repository
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Alternatively:**

If you have defined FeatureManager as following:

```
public class FeatureManager
    {
        public FeatureManager(EfFeatureDal featureDal) { }
    }
```

In that scenario, if you would like to call EfFeatureDal  in your FeatureList derived class you have to pass DbContext as its constructor parameter. You can do that in following manner:

```
public class FeatureList : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public FeatureList(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {

           
            _context = dbContext;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {

            FeatureManager feature = new FeatureManager(new EfFeatureDal(_context));
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** We are passing _context to EfFeatureDal because it has constructor dependency that is `public EfFeatureDal(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }`. Thus, Always keep in mind base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class. I would recommend you to [check our official document for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: Thank you so much !  i saw this answer before sleep, i will fix it according your answer. I understand my mistakes now. I hope it will be fixed

Comment: No worries, glad to assist you.

Comment: I dont know how to thank you. I been working on it more than 5 hours as a beginner programmer. Now it works! Long live .Net brotherhood :D

Comment: Now only i want to know why we cant recognize it( FeatureManager feature = new FeatureManager(new EfFeatureDal(_context));) out of invoke? I understand totally except that

Comment: Thanks for your response, doesn't that invoked? I didn't get your point actully. Would you kindly post a new question if you have any further question, I would try to explain you there.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that you made is you are trying to instantiate EfFeatureDal manually and you got stuck in the trap, actually you need to know about DI(Dependency Injection) Concept and use a IoC container to instantiate and inject EfFeatureDal object in your derived objects.
you can see a sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I used EfFeatureDal for database connection and inherited class want its paramater and paramater is dbcontext. Thats why when i tried to create another constructor it want to get paramater with 'base' keyword. And i cant do what i want. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).